# How to connect a SQL Server user to a new Login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am moving a SQL Server 2005 database to a new server using a backup. I was able to restore the backup to a new location without mishap.

The problem is, I have a number of Sql Server users who were connected to a login on the old server. Those logins were not there on the new server -- so I added them in (with the same passwords).

However, the SQL Server users are not automatically updated to those logins. In fact, in ManagementStudio, when I look at the properties of a user, it says the username is "without login", and the radio buttons are grayed out so I can't choose another one.

I tried this:

```
USE GlobalData --(the name of the database)
GO
ALTER USER Centration WITH LOGIN = Centration; --(both user and login are Centration)
```

and I get an error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN'.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

In management studio, select your database and then execute this command:

```
sp_change_users_login 'report'
```

This will produce a list of Users and Logins that are not mapped, then you can run the following command multiple times to map them; Run it per result that came back on the previous query:

```
sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'Centration', 'Centration';
go
sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'Centration2', 'Centration2';
```

etc etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that sp_change_users_login works. I read that ALTER USER had superceded it though, so I thought that was the way to go. However, our version of SS 2005 is RTM, no service packs installed, so maybe that's why ALTER USER did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are facing is called Orphaned users. And it is very common scenario when you have logins for database on one instance of SQL Server and you then restore that database to another instance of SQL Server.
But it is very easy to handle. This MSFT Support link shows how to transfer logins between two instance of SQL Server.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992

Or alternatively you can use Transfer Login task in SSIS and transfer logins from one instance to another instance.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137870.aspx